# What is the $E( \epsilon (x_i - \bar{x} ))$?

Tags: self-study, expected-value

I was checking a proof in my textbook and it says that $E( \epsilon (x_i -  \bar{x} )) = SST_x$ (this being the $\sum ( x_{i} -  \bar{x}) ^{2} )$ but I cannot figure it out why.

1. There are 5 assumptions of OLS (linearity in parameters, random sampling, sample variation in explanatory variable, zero conditional mean) and homoskedasticity.
2. $\epsilon$ is the error term (not residuals) $x_i$ is the independent variable and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean.

Comment: Delimit $\TeX$ with dollar signs \$.  Please explain what your notation means and what assumptions your textbook is making.

Comment: I doubt your formula. On the left side you have a constant. On the right you have a random variable.

Comment: IF your assumptions include that $\epsilon$ is independent of $x$ (automatic if your $x$ is a constant), then the expectation would be zero?